# UITableView is not showing the content of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7

I am making an app which involves UITableView. I have added the TableView to the viewController.
This is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

@end
```

And following is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController
{
NSArray *tabledata;
}

@synthesize tableview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
tabledata = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", nil];
tableview.delegate = self;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [tabledata count];
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 150.0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

When i am running this program it is showing me the table but it is not having any data and also the number of rows is not equal to 5. Please somebody help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are missing tableview.datasource = self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified code  from viewdidload

```
tabledata = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", nil];
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.